# Is it possible to add script to the end of the HEAD tag?

Tags: javascript

when using `addScriptDeclaration`, the script is added in the first  tag that is found inside the HEAD tag.

Is it possible to add it just before `</HEAD>`?

Comment: Read through this post which is similar to your problem: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22227/control-order-of-loaded-scripts

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the new feature **Child Templates** in Joomla 4.1.
Step by step details:

1. System > Site Templates > Cassiopeia Details and Files > and hit "Create Child Template"
2. Open `index.php` under /templates/cassiopeia
3. Select all the code and copy. Then close.
4. Go to System > Site Templates > and click to the newly created child template
5. Hit to "**New File**" and name it `index.php`
6. Paste the code.
7. Open `templateDetails.xml` and add the following code:
   `<field name="myJS" type="textarea" label="My JS script" />`
8. Edit child template `index.php` file, and add this new line inside `<head>` `</head>` tags:
   `<script><?php echo $this->params->get('myJS'); ?></script>`
9. Go to System > Site Template Styles and click on the child template
10. On the **Advanced** tab you will see a new field **My JS script**.
    There you can add your custom JS code.

That's all !

All credit goes to Dimitris Grammatiko and his presentation on JUG London !

Comment: Welcome at Joomla Stack Exchange. Please take our [tour]. Could you please add somewhat more information about that new Joomla 4.1 feature so that people know how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: @marian please [edit] your answer to be more explanatory about how to implement this feature and possibly how this feature works if you can.  Any supporting links/documentation/screenshots will make this answer more helpful to researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put  in the head, but its most common to put it before the  tag

Comment: The script must be in the template index.php, or you can use Sourcerer from Regular Labs

Comment: The system has flagged this post as being low-quality (because of its length/content).  I think perhaps the OP is asking about how to ensure that the new declaration is appended to the `<head></head>` as the last child inside of it.  In other words, the OP is trying to ensure that the declaration comes after all other declarations in the head tag.  Please do not extend your answer's advice by adding comments.  When you have additional relevant details to add, please edit your post so that the whole story is in one cohesive place (then delete your comment).

Answer (score 0):

There is a "dirty" way to do this.
Use regular labs rereplacer and simply replace in the head and replace

with
something before it

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/rereplacer

The swiss army penknife of the joomla world