# How can I add a local custom javascript file into the bottom of the template's index.php file?

Tags: templates, javascript, custom-action

I am writing some custom javascript in Joomla 4 Beta 6 to control various aspects of my custom front-end template's menus. It needs to load after the page has been rendered, so I want to add it at the bottom of the template's index.php file.

If I add the script in full it works fine.
If I add the code to /js/user.js and then add the full URL link to the file - as if it was an external file - in the bottom of the index.php file, it also works, fine, e.g:

```
<script src="https://my.website.com/templates/my_template/js/user.js"></script>
```

However, I'd rather not have the full link visible, but if I try to add it via a local reference (using both double and single quotes), it doesn't work, e.g.:

```
<script src="/js/user.js"></script>
```

I have also tried adding a php instruction like this:

```
<?php $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); $doc->addScript('templates/'. $this->template . '/js/user.js'); ?>
```

Which works for the template.js at the top of the file, but it doesn't work in this position at the bottom, either.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Casseopeia (default Joomla 4 frontend template) uses the following:

```
<jdoc:include type="scripts" />
```

inside the `<head>` tags at the top of the DOM, so any script added via `$doc->addScript()`, `HTMLHelper::script()` or `WebAssetManager` will be added up there.

That said, loading the file at the top doesn't really matter. You can simply defer the load and use the correct event listener, like so:

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

HTMLHelper::_('script', 'user.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true], ['type' => 'module']);
```

Note the `'type' => 'module'`. This does **NOT** mean a Joomla module. It means a Javascript module which is deferred automatically.

Inside your `user.js`, you can then execute your code once the DOM has loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Your code here
})
```

or once the entire page has loaded

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Your code here
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to get it to work. I added the code to the user.js file and then copied and pasted the line you provided, i.e. "HTMLHelper::...etc" inside the head tags before `<jdoc:include type="metas" />`. Was that the right place? Is there anything else I need to add into the index.php? Thanks.

Comment: That line is PHP, so you need to wrap it inside `<?php ... ?>` tags. You can add it near the top of the `index.php`

Comment: I have added exactly this: `<?php HTMLHelper::_('script', 'user.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true], ['type' => 'module']); ?>` - and no other new code - just above the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration, another attempt just below it but above the `<head>` tag, a third under the `<head>` tag and finally in the `<body>`. In all cases it just returns the J4 error message "Oops! An Error Occurred. The server returned a "500 Whoops, looks like something went wrong.".

Comment: Ahh, sorry, make sure you have `use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;` at the top of the file before adding that bit of code.

Comment: Great! It works perfectly, now. Many thanks :-)

Comment: You're more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

Instead I suggest you to use the Child Template feature following the guide and adapt it to your case.
This answer may help you: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/31954/15836