# Joomla 4 - Cassiopeia add JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, custom

I am using Cassiopeia and Joomla 4. I want to add a slideshow.js and user.css file.

I have already added the CSS file and it seems to be picking it up fine. I added the slideshow.js, but doesn't pick up automatically? How can I include this in the head?

Also, when I update Joomla will these files get wiped like they did with Joomla 3.x?

Note: I realise the CSS file appeared because I called it user.css, but with the slideshow file I need to load that after every other JS file.

Comment: Take a look on [this topic](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/is-it-possible-to-add-script-to-the-end-of-the-head-tag). This might be your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old method to add stylesheets and scripts to the doc head was to use the HTMLHelper. An good explanation how to use that: https://rolandd.com/blog/joomla/adding-stylesheets-scripts-and-images

**Since Joomla 4** you can use **Web Assets** to **add CSS/JS** to your doc head, see: https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Web_Assets

More info about WebAssetManager and using it in Joomla 4 templates:

- https://kevinsguides.com/guides/webdev/joomla4/ref/j4webassetmanager
- https://kevinsguides.com/guides/webdev/joomla4/joomla-4-templates/develop-j4-template

**Never edit Joomla's core files**. Core hacks can cause issues and can be overwritten with the next update. Instead you could use Template Overrides or Child Themes or add them using plugins.

More Tips & Tricks regarding Joomla's Cassiopeia template: https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/february-2022/joomla-4-cassiopeia-template-a-bunch-of-tips-tricks